# Using Ruby on Rail's Authlogic gem, how do I display the login form on all pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication, authlogic, rubygems

I followed the tutorial exactly: http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example

But I am wondering how can I get the login form to appear on all pages when someone isn't logged in?

I searched Google and looked at many forums for answers, but the only solutions I could find require me to define `@user_session = UserSession.new` for every page that has the login form.

What I'd like to do is put the form in the `application.html.erb` file and only have it show up when people are logged out (which I've managed to do).

However, I'd like to only have to put `@user_session = UserSession.new` in one controller, such as the `ApplicationController`, as it is very non-RESTful to have to put that piece of code on every single page. If I leave the form code in the `application.html.erb` and that code is not defined for a page in the controller, then the page will give an error.

I don't want to have to define it for every page, as it will be a lot of work to have to remove it from every single page if I ever decide to get rid of the login form or something.

In short: I want to put the Login form on every single page of my site, and only have to put `@user_session = UserSession.new` in one controller.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ApplicationController`, you can do the following:

```
before_filter :prepare_new_session

def prepare_new_session
  @user_session = UserSession.new if current_user.blank?
end
```

That'll give you a `@user_session` object for every action (if a user is not currently logged in).  That way, you can include the form on every page by placing it in the `layouts/application.html.erb` file.